# Java - Cast element of object array as an int

Tags: java

For a homework assignment, I need to take the array acc, which is an array of account numbers, and compare its contents with some user input.  An error is produced comparing acc[i] with acctNum. Casting as int using (Integer) or (int) is not working.

```
private static int printArrayTest(Scanner bleh, Account [] acc)
    {
        int acctNum;    

        System.out.println("Account number: ");
        acctNum = bleh.nextInt();           

        for (int i=0; i<acc.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(acc[i]);
            if (acctNum == (Integer) acc[i])
                return acctNum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, an `Account` object certainly isn't an `Integer` object.

Comment: Maybe your Account object has some kind of int property, as "accountNumber" that you can print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your array contains 'Account' objects. You cannot cast Account to an int because it is not a number. You have to access the account number field of your Account object, possibly something like:

```
 if (acctNum == acc[i].getAccountNumber())
```

You need to create a method inside your Account class which allows you to retrieve the account number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an object of an arbitrary type, for example `Account`, to any other arbitrary type, such as `Integer`. Casting does not mean that somehow the object is automatically converted from one type to another type.

The only thing that a cast does, is tell the compiler that it shouldn't check the type of the object you're casting - it should just assume the object is whatever you say it is. If you cast an `Account` object to an `Integer`, then what you're doing is telling the compiler  that the object is an `Integer` and it should not complain about it.

But when you run the program, the JVM will still check if the cast is valid, in other words, it will check if the object that you're casting is indeed of the type that you're casting it to. If it isn't, a `ClassCastException` is thrown. Which is what happens in your program, because an `Account` object is not an `Integer` object.

The solution is what Memento Mori wrote in his answer: don't cast, but call the appropriate method on the `Account` object.